# MapMarker has no propTypes for native prop 'AIRMapMarker.testID'

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps (v-0.16.4)
It works fine with ios but MapView.marker is not working on android

the complete error statement is-

MapMarker has no propTypes for native prop 'AIRMapMarker.testID' of native type string. If you have not changed this prop yourself, this usually means that your version of native code and Javascript code are out of sync. Updating both should make this error go away.

[this is image for error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYkge.png)

My map file is-

```html
<MapView
           provider={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PROVIDER_DEFAULT :  PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
            style={{
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              position: 'absolute'
            }}
          region={{
            latitude:128.569184,
            longitude: 73.765760,
            latitudeDelta: 0.00942,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0843
          }}
          ref={map => { this.map = map }}
        >
          <MapView.Marker
          map = {this.map}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: 128.568806,
              longitude: 73.765210
            }}
            image={"http://pokeapi.co/media/sprites/pokemon/1.png"}
            title='ETHEL and Friends'
            >
            </MapView.Marker>
        </MapView>
```

Comment: Did you try to do what the error says?

Comment: I am not getting that error properly. I tried to provide React.Proptypes n=but it failed

Comment: what do you mean not getting properly? Do you mean you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand what the error is ?

Comment: Its saying that native android module for react-native-maps is different from you are using in javascript. You probably installed the library incorrectly. Try removing and reinstalling.

Comment: Yes, i removed the library and reinstalled it. But still it is showing same error. The map is visible correctly, only issue with the mapview.marker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md) for `MapView.Marker` and find out your `image` prop has a wrong value. You need to set it as a local ImageSource type.

**From the docs:**

> **image** (**ImageSource**)
>
> *A custom image to be used as the marker's icon. Only local image resources are allowed to be used.*

**Example**

```
<MapView ref={map => { this.map = map; }}>
  <MapView.Marker
    map={this.map}
    coordinate={{latitude: 128.568806, longitude: 73.765210}}
    image={require('media/sprites/pokemon/1.png')}
    title='ETHEL and Friends'
  >
  </MapView.Marker>
</MapView>
```

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your response , i tried this code as you modified still the marker is not visible and showing same error

Comment: Which version of react-native-maps are you using?

Comment: react-native-maps@0.16.4

Comment: can you try to downgrade your version please? Sometimes react-native-maps can have bugs and using older and more stable version might be required.

Comment: Can you please suggest me which version can work properly?

Comment: Ican't possible know but you can first try the latest 0.15.* version I guess.

Comment: Hey, Thank you. Its working fine now. I changed version to react-native-maps@0.15.2

Comment: Great! Follow up the repository for new versions. Maybe the issue is going to be solved on the next one. Who knows. Good coding

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to fix it for a long time.